# jquery retrieve data with in tags using regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

here is the example

```
<style>body{color:red;width:200px; }</style>
```

looking to strip the style tag and retrieve the data..but wanaa regx for strip tags and get data between them...someone plz help me...

Answer (score 1):

If this is your css:

```
<style>
body{
   color:red;
   width:200px;
 }
</style>
```

Then you can *reliably* get the body's width like this:

```
$('body').css('width');
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/3SkY5/1/

See http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('style:first').html();
```

... for instance. Modify as needed.

I don't think regular expressions will be the best solution here. As somebody else will doubtlessly explain to you in a link, html is not regular.

Comment: sorry.. my question is how can retrive data between two tags using regular exression .. please help me ..

Comment: looking for strip tag with jquery .. please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$('style').html();
```